# Как сделать в линукс Ubuntu из Bash скрипта сервис?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, service

Собственно вопрос, как сделать из Bash скрипта в Linux сервис (демон), с возможностью проверки его на работоспособность перезапуском в случаи сбоя или зависания?

Comment: А вам точно нужно его делать демоном??? Можно же его запустить без вывода на автозапуске...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этой цели можно создать юнит systemd. Для начала нужно создать файл с названием my.service и поместим его в /etc/systemd/system.

```
[Unit]
Description = My demon

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/my
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Раздел [Unit] хранит общие сведения о юните. В данном случае он содержит только описание (Description).

Раздел [Service] объединяет сведения, необходимые для выполнения юнитом его задач. Type определяет тип сервиса (не путайте его с разновидностями юнитов), oneshot означает, что сервис должен выполнить разовую задачу и завершиться. ExecStop указывает скрипт, который должен быть выполнен перед остановкой сервиса. Есть еще ExecStart, этот параметр используется чаще и определяет команду, которая должна быть выполнена сразу после запуска сервиса. RemainAfterExit=true предписывает systemd считать процесс активным после его завершения.

Секция [Install] содержит сведения о том, при каких обстоятельствах должен быть запущен сервис. WantedBy=multi-user.target устанавливает запуск при обычной загрузке компьютера.

Далее нужно поместить ваш скрипт (my) в `/usr/local/bin/`. Командами:

```
sudo systemctl enable my
sudo systemctl start my
```

можно добавить сервис в автозагрузку и запустить его, чтобы он включился.

Более подробно можете ознакомиться в [этой статье](http://www.linuxrussia.com/systemd-create-own-unit.html) и в [man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd). Также может быть полезна [статья с хабра](https://habr.com/company/southbridge/blog/255845/).