# Греется ноутбук. Проблемы с настройкой частоты на i5-8300H (ТЧ 2.30 ГГц, ОС Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, cpu, процессор

Во время игр частота на потоках дотигает ~4ГГц и, соответственно, средняя температура ядер ~90 градусов. Делал из-под рута

```
echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[номер потока]/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

и все прекрасно работатет. Только в рамках одной сессии. Перезагрузка - все,  заново прописывать для всех восьми потоков.

Как сделать так чтобы значение, задаваемое этой командой, оставалось навсегда?

Comment: дык, похоже, что всё уже установлено... Почему ты считаешь, что `echo 2000000` в `scaling_max_freq` не помогает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так чтобы значение, задаваемое этой командой, оставалось навсегда?

Основная идея в том, чтобы они выполнялись при загрузке.

- Можно сделать это, например, «классическим» способом, добавив их в `/etc/rc.local` (дебианы и бубунты с `system.d` на сегодняшний день поддерживают это из коробки). `rc.local` должен выглядеть как-то так:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  for f in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq; do
    echo 2000000 >$f;
  done

  exit 0
  ```

  Также надо не забыть дать право скрипту на исполнение: `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`
- Можно написать [свой unit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922603/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81-ubuntu-%d0%b8%d0%b7-bash-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81/922612#922612) для этого.
- Можно воспользоваться готовым сценарием, который идёт в комплекте с `cpupower` просто настроив его...